# How to get the duration of the animation of the slide and shape using python-pptx

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerpoint

I am trying to get the properties (duration) of the transition a slide and animation of  shape. I am currently using python-pptx to extract data from a powerpoint file. I have read the documentation but I can't seem to find the solution to my problem.